# Using hidden fields during HTTP post for the reload of same page postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, hidden-field, html.beginform, html.hiddenfor

I have a View where the User can leave a feedback comment in regards to the content video that is playing on the page. Using the following code I am able to manually enter the UserID and ContentID and it saves to the database without problem.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Screencast", "Media", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {              
          <div class="row">
            <div class="six columns">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="six columns">
                  @Html.LabelFor(c => c.FeedbackComment.UserID)
                  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.FeedbackComment.UserID)
                </div>
                <div class="six columns">
                  @Html.LabelFor(c => c.FeedbackComment.ContentID)
                  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.FeedbackComment.ContentID)
                </div>   
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="twelve columns">
                    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.FeedbackComment.FeedbackString)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.FeedbackComment.FeedbackString)
                  </div>
                </div>        
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          
          <input type="submit" value="Submit button" class="medium button bottom20"/>
        }
```

However, when the user is on the page before the HTTP post I actually have the related variables in my Model called:

```
Model.User.UserID
Model.SelectedItem.ContentID
```

I want to pass these in as hidden fields but when I try to do either:

```
@HtmlHiddenFor(c => c.FeedbackComment.UserID, @Model.User.UserID)
@HtmlHiddenFor(c => c.FeedbackComment.ContentID, @Model.SelectedItem.ContentID)
```

or

```
@HtmlHidden("UserID",@Model.User.UserID)
@HtmlHidden("ContentID",@Model.User.UserID)
```

Then these values are returned null despite the values being populated before the post. I read about a workaround of putting the input tags in manually but when I did this the @Using.HtmlBeginForm was returning an error of not being set to an instance of an object

Can someone please help me to understand how I can pass these values to the same page using the values I have in the model prior to the post.

Comment: Why do you not write this as  "@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.UserID)"  ?

Comment: I tried this also the this does not return a valid model state

Comment: Perhaps, relation between view and controller is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following view model (partial):

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     public User User { get; set; }

     public SelectedItem SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

You can bind the these properties to a hidden form element. When you post back these properties will still contain their values.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.User.UserID)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedItem.ContentID)
```

Your action method:

```
public ActionResult YourActionMethod(YourViewModel viewModel)
{
     // When you debug here you will see that the values are retained
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: So should each form be called as a partial?

Comment: Nope partial is not required. You use partial when you use the same classes when they need to be split up.